# Is there a way to compare multiple values in a linq expression to a generic list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a complex entity object I am querying that has values that need to be compared to a generic list in order to select the correct objects. I am trying to find a way to compare the Id values in the the entity object to all the values in my list without having to put the query inside a loop.

This is what I have:

Generic List:

```
    List<int> input = new List<int>()
                           {
                                 3,4,5....
                           };
```

My Query-Does not work:

```
      ManagerToGetRepo mgr = new ManagerToGetRepo();
      var result = mgr.GetAllData()
                      .Where(a=>a.someObject.anotherObj.Id == input.Values);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `List<T>.Contains` method to see if each value is in the collection

```
var result = mgr.GetAllData()
                .Where(a => input.Contains(a.someObject.anotherObj.Id));
```

Comment: I had not thought you could do it the other way around using linq, much appreciated.